# DX Error when running Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I am trying to set up my Android Studio project with al its dependencies. But when i try to run my project i get the following error messages:

```
Android Dex: [AndroidVI] Unable to execute DX
Android Dex: [AndroidVI] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/androidquery/util/Constants;
```

Can anybody help me with this

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18301856/2591002) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15705407/2591002). Might help you..

Comment: download build tools of Api 19 and you will get the solution

Comment: You have add same Jar files twise. Go to Properties-->Build Path-->Libraries--> remove extra added library, just keep the latest one. thn go Order and Export chk all chk boxes.

Answer (score 16):

Check Whether You added Same jar files more than once.

If yes,Remove any one of them from libs folder and clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Your Proguard is running or not.